# Is there a scalable way to use mesh volumes in Unity such that fragments drawn within them use a different shader path?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-shaders

I want to include invisible geometry in my scene which, for all portions of a mesh within the geometry, one texture/shading path on their shader/material is used, blending to portions of the geometry NOT within the invisible volume using a different texture/shading path.

Concretely, what I'm trying to build is an environment where certain regions are "normal colored" and anything outside those regions uses a drab/gray/cracked appearance.

I know I could add (especially algorithmic) volumes as parameters to a shader (treated similarly to lights, I suppose), but that could get fairly intensive fairly quickly if I end up with many volumes hitting any given mesh, not to mention the overhead of checking objects for intersection with each volume.

Currently I'm using URP forward rendering in Unity 2020.3.28f1.

Comment: _"I want to include invisible geometry in my scene which, for all portions of a mesh within the geometry, one texture/shading path on their shader/material is used, blending to portions of the geometry NOT within the invisible volume using a different texture/shading path"_ - Is the _net effect_ anything like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szsWx9IQVDI)

Comment: That's not the effect I'm hoping for, but I might be able to use the custom renderer setup.

What I want is more like having a beacon, and all geometry near the beacon (e.g., within a radius) uses its proper texture, whereas geometry not nearby to a beacon uses a different texture/shader path.

I said "invisible geometry" because I don't want to render the shapes of the bounding volumes, but perhaps that made my question less clear as a result?

Comment: I get you.  Do check it out all the same as its pretty amazing what you can do with custom renderer and pipelines :)